# Serialize a type with XmlSerializer by omitting it when it has a null field

Tags: c#, serialization, ixmlserializable

Here's a self-contained sample program that demonstrates my question: https://gist.github.com/jennings/46c20733df559d02b9ad

I'm writing a type `Maybe<T>` which looks like this:

```
public struct Maybe<T> : IXmlSerializable where T : class
{
    readonly T _value;
    //...
}
```

Can I accomplish one of these two goals of the serialization?

1. If a property of type `Maybe<T>` is being serialized, do not emit the property at all if its `_value` is null (string properties seem to have this behavior).
2. Serialize the `_value` *in place* of the `Maybe<T>`.

So if a class using my type looks like this:

```
public class AnyRandomObjectUsingMyType
{
    public Maybe<string> MaybeAString{ get; set; }
}
```

Then if `MaybeaString._value` is null, I want this when serialized:

```
<AnyRandomObjectUsingMyType>
</AnyRandomObjectUsingMyType>
```

I *do not* want either of these:

```
<AnyRandomObjectUsingMyType>
  <MaybeAString xsi:nil="true" />
</AnyRandomObjectUsingMyType>

<AnyRandomObjectUsingMyType>
  <MaybeAString></MaybeAString>
</AnyRandomObjectUsingMyType>
```

**I don't want to configure the serialization on `AnyRandomObjectUsingMyType`** because there will be many, many of those. I'd much rather have `Maybe<T>` control this so everywhere gets the same behavior.

---

## Some context

The type `Maybe<T>` is meant as a drop-in replacement for a `T`. But we use XML serialization in several places. If there's an object like this:

```
// Version 1 class
public class SomethingBeingSerialized
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

When SomeValue is null, this class serializes to this:

```
<SomethingBeingSerialized>
</SomethingBeingSerialized>
```

I want to be able to change the class to this:

```
// Version 2 class
public class SomethingBeingSerialized
{
    public Maybe<string> SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

And I want the serialized representation to be identical. If a V1 app deserializes, it gets a null string. If a V2 app deserializes, it gets a `Maybe<string>` which represents None.

I've tried doing this in my `IXmlSerializable.WriteXml` method, but when it gets called, the XmlWriter seems to already have written this much to it's underlying stream:

```
<SomeValue
```

So it seems like by the time my `WriteXml` method gets called, it's too late. Maybe there's another way to control this?

If I could specify to the serializer: "As soon as you encounter an object of type `Maybe<T>`, serialize its `_value` property in place of the `Maybe<T>`", it would also accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Do not make Maybe serializable, make it's container serializable.  You can have an extension method for Maybe that builds an XML Node for it's value as you desire, and in the class that's being serialized would incorporate the return value of the extension method.

```
public static class MaybeMethods
{
    public static string SerializeValue<T>(this Maybe<T> source)
    {
         // Do the work to serialize the value in Maybe
    }
}
```

In your hosting classes's serialization method

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
     var maybeXml = myMaybe.SerializeValue();

     // if maybeXml is not null, include it in your writer
}
```

Comment: I know I could control the serialization on the container, but I don't want to do that because there will be many, many of those. I'd much rather have `Maybe<T>` control this so every container class gets the same behavior.